# Download all transitive dependencies on mvn install

Tags: maven, build, dependency-management

I'm currently starting to get into Maven.
I've been tasked to create a maven environment for a large pre-existing project and I want the build environment to be as portable as possible. My problem is, that on a machine with a fresh maven installation, my project does not seem to download transitive dependencies when in run 'mvn install'.
Currently maven comes up with a build order like this:

```
ProjA
ProjB
```

Project A has some dependencies and code that Project B depends on. So I set Project B to only depend on Project A. When running 'mvn install' though, compilation of ProjB fails, because it says it is missing a package that ProjA depends on.
Am I running the wrong command for a fresh setup, or do I have to add a specific line in the POM of Project B to make it work on a fresh machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it is fine. When you run `mvn install`, all transitive dependencies are pulled. The missing package must have some other reason.

Comment: @JFMeier to be more specific ProjA has a dependency on org.apache.commons which ProjB also requires. I've not added org.apache.commons as dependecy in ProjB since it should already get it from ProjA. If ProjB itself also needs org.apache.common, and not only in the context of code from ProjA, would I have to add a separate dependency in ProjB?

Comment: It is recommended to do that, but not required. Look at `mvn dependency:tree` to see the transitive dependencies. Note that scopes like `test` or `provided` on a dependency could kill transitivity.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably do that then. Since everything should be in the same dependency scope, I don't think it should be scope issue.